# The number of partial orders of finite set.

Tags: order-theory

My question is about the number of partial orders of finite set. For example, if $S=\{a, b\}$, then there are 4 partial orders $\{ (a, a), (b, b) \}$, $\{ (a, a), (a, b), (b, b) \}$, $\{ (a, a), (b, a), (b, b) \}$, $\{ (a, a), (a, b), (b, a), (b, b) \}$. Then, how many are there partial orders if $|S|=n$?

I tried to count for the case $|S|=3$, $\{ (a, a), (b, b), (c, c) \}$, $\{ (a, a), (b, b), (c, c), (a, b) \}$, $\{ (a, a), (b, b), (c, c), (a, b), (b, c), (a, c) \}$, and so on. But it is too inefficient and does not give any insight.

If this is a difficult question, then I want to just know the case of $|S|=3$.

Comment: The online encyclopedia of integer sequences has [a list for the first couple](https://oeis.org/A001035) $n$. Also, see [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/241782/finding-all-partial-order-relations-on-a-set).

Comment: Also, $\{(a,a), (a,b), (b,a), (b,b)\}$ is not a partial order since antisymmetry forbids to have both $(a,b)$ and $(b,a)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the usual terminology, a [*partial order*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set) is required be *antisymmetric*: if $x\le y$ and $y\le x$, then $x=y$. Thus there are only three partial orders on a two-element set; your fourth example in not antisymmetric.

Apparently, you want to count the more general *quasi-orders* aka [*preorders*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preorder), i.e., reflexive transitive relations. (On a *finite* set, there is a one-to-one correspondence between quasi-orders and topologies.)

The number of quasi-orders (or equivalently, the number of topologies) on an $n$-element set is sequence [A000798](http://oeis.org/A000798) at the [OEIS](https://oeis.org/). There are $29$ quasi-orders on a $3$-element set.

Answer (score 2):

Each finite pos (partially ordered set) has to have at least one minimal element.

Consider 3-set $\ X:=\{a\ b\ c\}.\ $ First, let $a$ be the **unique** minimal element. There are exactly three different partial orders in $\{b\ c\}.\ $ The same when $\ b\ $ or $\ c\ $ is the only minimal element in $\ X.\ $ Each of those partial orders in a 2-element set extends uniquely over the third element that is minimal. Every two of these partial orders in $\ X\ $ are different. Thus, there are exactly $9=3\cdot 3\ $
partial orders in $\ X\ $ that have exactly one minimal element.

Now, let $\ a\ $ and $\ b\ $ be the only minimal elements in $\ X\ $ (so that $\ c\ $ is not minimal). We have exactly three partial orders like this in $\ X.\ $ If the lonely non-minimal element is $\ b\ $ or $\ a\ $, each time we get 3 different partial orders, and all of such $\ 3\cdot 3=9\ $ partial orders are different. Thus, so far, we have 9+9=18 different partial orders.

Finally, there is exactly one partial order such that all elements of $\ X\ $ are minimal. This gives us finally the answer 1+18=19.

**THEOREM** There are exactly $\ 19\ $ different partial orders in any fixed 3-set.