# Counting partially ordered relations in a finite set

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I have the following set: A={1,2,3,4}

I need to count the number of total partially ordered relations on this set.

I've tried to brute force but I realized there are too many,
I have also tried to count separately the reflexive relations and the transitive relations using combinatorics but it didn't work well.

How am I supposed to approach this question?

Comment: As an aside, counting reflexive relations is easy.  Auto-include every pair of the form $(x,x)$, and then answer yes or no to whether each other pair is included, giving $2^{n(n-1)}$ reflexive relations on a set with $n$ elements.  As for counting partial orders... that is challenging... [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/241782/finding-all-posets-on-a-set?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: See also: https://oeis.org/A001035

Comment: With "*the number of **total** partially ordered relations*", do you mean "the number of partial relations that are also [*total*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order)" (i.e. the number of linear relations), or do you mean "the *total number* of partial relations"? If it is the first, this is simply the number of permutations on the sequence $(1,2,3,4)$, that is, $4\cdot 3\cdot 2=24$.